# The not-so-useless "yes" bash command: how to confirm a command in every loop

Tags: bash

I wrote a loop to unzip all zip files in a directory.

```
for f in *zip
do
    unzip $f
done
```

However, I have to confirm the overwrite at every step:

```
replace file123.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
```

How can I rewrite a loop to send at every cycle the same command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Wonderful, maybe one of the few cases where ***yes*** is still useful

Try with:

```
for f in *zip
do
    yes | unzip $f
done
```

Which will work printing "y" at every command.

Or alternatively, you can specify the string provided by yes, like:

```
for f in *zip
do
    yes A | unzip $f
done
```

Comment: <yes> can provide also a "never overwrite" capability, which seems to lack among the unzip options

Answer (score 9):

```
unzip -o $f
```

per the docs

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
unzip -o
```

in your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *zip
do
   echo "yes" | unzip $f
done
```