# Is the program `yes` used for anything significant?

Tags: linux, unix

When I first came across the `yes` program in *nix I couldn't think of a significant use for it.

How is this program used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The not-so-useless "yes" bash command: how to confirm a command in every loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941242/the-not-so-useless-yes-bash-command-how-to-confirm-a-command-in-every-loop)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`yes` is meant to automate interactive programs that want confirmation before taking action.

```
yes | rm -ri foo
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
rm -rf foo
```

The difference is that `-f` will also proceed in case of failure.

Answer (score 10):

Another one may be quickly adding n lines of the same text to a file:

```
 yes "this is the text I want to add to a file"|head -200>myFile.txt
```

which creates a file with 200 lines of the same text.

Answer (score 4):

Its output can be used to say "yes" to some running process that stops to ask for (y/n) input.