# How to enter a string automatically when a command results in a prompt?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I want to download source code from git using a script.

The following `git` command results in a prompt:

```
git clone ssh://url.com/repo.git git_test3
Cloning into 'git_test3'...
The authenticity of host 'url.com (1.1.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is .
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I developed the following script in order to enter "yes" automatically by the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
git_clone() {
    git clone ssh://url.com/repo.git test <<EOF > /dev/null
yes
EOF
}

git_clone
```

but it does not work.  The script always results in the prompt `(yes/no)`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can do what you want with an `expect` script.  See http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try the **yes** command, it might work. Try this, `yes yes | git clone ssh://url.com/repo.git test` , Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416887/is-the-program-yes-used-for-anything-significant

Comment: @ishaan That's just another way of providing repeated text to the standard input of `git`, which is what the OP is already doing. The problem is that it's not `git` asking for a response, it's `ssh`, and `ssh` isn't reading from standard input, but directly from the terminal.

Comment: Ahh, learned a new thing today. Well similar question has already been answered before, maybe OP can have a look there and find a solution to the problem, refer : http://serverfault.com/questions/447028/non-interactive-git-clone-ssh-fingerprint-prompt

Answer (score 1):

That message (and interaction) comes from the ssh command, rather than git itself.  (This is useful indirectly since it means you know which command to target if your goal is just to avoid the interaction: you just need to tell ssh that you don't actually care about authenticating the other host, or use a protocol such as `git://...` instead of `ssh://...`.)

If you really want to handle the interaction yourself, you will need to open a pty (perhaps via expect, as [Wolf noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907227/how-to-enter-string-automatically-when-prompt-is-returned-in-a-command#comment57550493_34907227)).  The reason is that ssh opens `/dev/tty` so as to force interaction with the user, rather than reading from any pipes or file redirections.  You must therefore supply it with a controlling terminal that is under your own program's control.